# PerformanceCounter throwing AccessViolationException at my confused face

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls, performancecounter

Memory class

```
        static PerformanceCounter MemoryUsageCounter = new PerformanceCounter
        {
            CategoryName = "Memory",
            CounterName = "Available MBytes"
        };

        static int CurrentMemory = 16317;
        static int CurrentUsage;

        public static string[] ReturnUsage()
        {
            CurrentUsage = Convert.ToInt32(CurrentMemory - Math.Round(MemoryUsageCounter.NextValue()));
            float usage = CurrentMemory - CurrentUsage;
            double percent = (usage / CurrentMemory) * 100;
            return new string[] { $"{CurrentUsage.ToString()}MB", $"{Math.Round(percent).ToString()}%" };
        }
```

UserControl

```
        private void Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            string[] mem = Memory.ReturnUsage();
            e.Graphics.DrawString(mem[0], new Font(new FontFamily("Exo 2.0 Medium"), 8, FontStyle.Bold), new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(170, Color.White)), 53, 22);
            e.Graphics.DrawString(mem[1], new Font(new FontFamily("Exo 2.0 Medium"), 8, FontStyle.Bold), new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(100, Color.White)), 53, 33);
        }
```

The method in the Memory class is called from a user control. Return memory usage in MB and %. I put this user control in a panel which is in my form. Trying to get `NextValue()` via `ReturnUsage();`gives me an AccessViolationException and I don't understand why.

Wait theres more:
Calling the same method via `string a = ReturnUsage()[0];` in the main form's code before calling it within the user control somehow makes this error go away.

I am a confused banana please tell me what im doing wrong.

Comment: Post the user control's code fully please.

Comment: You are not using the PerformanceCounter anywhere

Comment: Provided all the relevant code and a more detailed explanation, if you need anything else do tell.

Comment: Is `ReturnUsage()` supposed to be `static`? It looks like you're accessing the `Memory` class directly. This also affects the `PerformanceCounter` declaration.

Comment: It is indeed `static`, will fix the post

Comment: @Jimi affect it in what way? I really want to keep the memory code in its own class and not put it in the user control code itself.

Comment: How is it possible that you *forgot* that the method was `static`, so the code presented here needed to be updated? Is the class also `static`? -- Well, now the `PerformanceCounter` has become static, too... And now it works, right?

Comment: When im an idiot, thats it no more edits. I was testing the code left and right thats why I pasted things from other places were they werent static. AccessViolation still happens.

Comment: It causes OutOfMemory exception on my x64 windows 10 if in override OnPaint(). Works well when run as administrator

Comment: Dear ModuleLFS, where do you call Invalidate() ?

Comment: Read the Remarks section of [PerformanceCounter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.performancecounter)

Comment: From a timer thats in that usercontrol. @OguzOzgul

Comment: It works well with the timer. You just need to skip reading NextValue() for the initial calls (I saw that it is triggered two times during form activation) to OnPaint. I managed it using a boolean field which is set right before Invalidate(). I could not make it crash again (resizing, minimizing, restoring, maximizing etc.)

Comment: If you're planning on showing these values for a long time, I suggest to define the Font and the SolidBrush objects as Fields, then dispose of these object in the Dispose() method of the class: you don't need to create a new Font all the time and the SolidBrush object **needs** to be disposed: you cannot have `new SolidBrush(()` inside a drawing method. If you have seen it used that way, it was just a shortcut for an example.

Comment: Sure @Jimi ill optimize the code there. As for the AccessViolation issue, it somehow dissapeared when I ran the executable as admin from windows explorer which crashed. After that I ran it in Visual Studio and it doesn't crash now.... uuuuuuuuuuuuh.

Comment: Open up your `app.manifest` file and check the current options with the [Targeting your application for Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/targeting-your-application-at-windows-8-1) and [How User Account Control works](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/identity-protection/user-account-control/how-user-account-control-works) info (this is just the basic info about this matter).